# The Very Low Quality flag is broken

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts

NAA is for answers that don't make any attempt to answer the question:

- asdfjhaklsefuh
- I like cows
- Thanks!
- Did you find the solution?
- Sometimes link-only answers, but not all moderators agree

VLQ is for posts that are:

- <del>Very low quality</del> (**no**, that's downvote).
- <del>Have severe formatting or content problems</del> (**no**, that's also downvote, especially for formatting problems (Y U NO EDIT?)).
- <del>Unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed</del> (**no**, that's downvote, and delete vote for the (10|20)kers (i.e. nobody)).
- <del>Utter garbage</del> (**no**, that's too subjective and a moderator will likely disagree with you a significant amout of the time)
- <del>Questions that need help getting closed and the flag to use on horrible answers that have 0 or less votes (because NAA tends to be declined more for some reason)</del> (**no**, while the LQRQ queue may appear to be designed for that, moderators hate it as it reportedly goes into their queue too)
- NAA, [gibberish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibberish), non-English, rudeness, anything which a moderator can't *not delete* (this is the answer for making the moderators happy in practice).

The VLQ flag is badly defined, misused, misimplemented for questions (closing instead of deleting (which is what the flag is for(?)) in the LQRQ), and nobody agrees on their usage. For answers, it's even more confusing since there are ***2*** indistinguishable flags both with confusing definitions.

Can we create a concrete definition of VLQ for questions and answers that goes to *one* queue and doesn't colide with NAA? I would like a "recommend deletion" flag (including irrelevant answers that would require seeing the question to review). And a "convert to comment" flag.

… it's purpose isn't for gibberish apparently, that [counts as "abuse"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/237813).

Comment: Well, obviously "I like cows" is not an answer. It should at all times be replaced with "I like unicorns" to turn it into a high-quality all-explaining answer.

Comment: [I like cows!](http://gemsfromstackexchange.tumblr.com/image/80886386299)

Comment: @hichris123 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FavUpD_IjVY

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195673/it-shouldn-t-be-possible-to-flag-questions-as-very-low-quality

Comment: @minitech That implies it isn't vague on answers as well.

Comment: It isn’t always. You wrote: “unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed (no, that's downvote, and delete vote for the (10|20)kers (i.e. nobody)).” – no, it actually is “use this flag”, for the people who aren’t the referenced “nobody”.

Comment: @minitech Sometimes, but not "use jQuery modal" (it's useless and should be converted to a comment or deleted but still is an attempt to answer the question) or a link-only answer (you can copy the content from the link to the answer so not "unsalvageable thru editing"). Also what "needs to be removed"?

Comment: People who use it on those answers are wrong, and perhaps that needs to be clarified, but that wasn’t the intent of the question I linked to. Things that need to be removed include: gibberish.

Comment: @minitech So there should be a flag for useless non-VLQ answers and the description of VLQ should be clarified.

Comment: What about comment-answers?

Comment: @SimonKuang They would ideally be converted to comments.

Comment: "unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed" is exactly what the VLQ flag is for, I don't know why you're denying that it is. Questions you've flagged VLQ that fit this description have been closed. VLQ flags where you should have used close votes have been declined. Just because you don't use the flag consistently doesn't mean it's broken.

Comment: For non-answers (including comments posted as answers), use the… Not an Answer flag! @SimonKuang

Comment: @BilltheLizard What is "unlikely"? When do questions "need" to be removed? Why should I flag instead of just CV? When should I flag instead of just CV? Answers flagged VLQ get deleted, questions get closed - why? What is the difference between a low-quality answer and a low-quality question? When should I use VLQ vs NAA? How does the system treat them differently?

Comment: @minitech When is an answer a comment? I used to think "use flexbox" is a comment, but now I know you're not supposed to flag it.

Comment: @bjb568: Yeah, you are supposed to flag it. As for deciding when, please feel free to *use your best judgement*. It’s a flag, after all.

Comment: @bjb568 "Unlikely" means "not likely." When they fit the description of VLQ. See previous. When a post doesn't fit the description of one of the close reasons. Because that's how we process questions, first close, then delete. One is an answer and the other is a question. Use VLQ when a post fits the description of VLQ, and use NAA when it fits the description of NAA. The system treats them the same. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190639/1288)

Comment: @BilltheLizard Did you just define VLQ as itself? "Because that's how we process questions, first close, then delete" Except when I poke somebody with actual del/undel prigs (i.e. mods) when it goes straight to delete… (seems like the only reason things aren't deleted immediately is because there is nobody with the rights to delete it immediately). Why are there 2 flags that do the same thing?

Comment: @bjb568 VLQ is already defined. I don't need to redefine it for you. You had some flags declined because you weren't using VLQ consistently. That doesn't mean there's something wrong with the flag. Just stop using it when you have a close vote that you can use instead.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I'm not complaining that I got flags declined. I'm complaining that me, and a lot of other users [find the VLQ flag confusing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=very+low+quality). "Already defined"? I have definitions above of how people use it, meta posts, how the system is designed, etc. Which one is correct? If it is a post that is of such low quality the user who posted it must be insane and therefore cannot respond to comments asking for clarification which would allow edits that would make it not satisfy this definition impossible, it's still subjective and recursive.

Comment: Why don't we just ditch VLQ entirely and keep NAA? It seems to be the least ambiguous of the two.

Comment: @JasonC For answers, that seems like a good idea. "Not an answer" is pretty self-explanatory and intricacies are well-explained. There should still be a flag for questions tho…

Comment: Maybe we could call low quality questions NARQ.

Comment: @JasonC: Because they’re not the same thing. NAA is much more useful. (If you’re not suggesting combining them, though, I’m all for it. Then we can add a “gibberish” flag that is non-confusing.)

Comment: @bjb568 Yes, just for answers.

Comment: @minitech I'm all about replacing VLQ with "gibberish" on answers but; it's not that I think VLQ == NAA on answers; it's just that I think VLQ essentially boils down to a subset of NAA and there doesn't *actually* seem to be much added value to VLQ compared to how open it is for misuse. Technically, if an answer's Q is L enough to be VL, then it's not really an answer. While we can get very specific and nitpicky with descriptions the fact is people will flag whatever one fits into the sentence "This answer is \_\_\_\_" by their own interpretation (e.g. using "low quality" for "crappy idea").

Comment: @JasonC: I think VLQ is more of a superset of NAA, and one that’s a bit annoying to deal with. Any answer that isn’t an answer should be removed and is low quality, but VLQ deals with more than that – or, at least, that’s how it’s used. Things that are hard to read, things that are wrong according to some people, things in different languages…

Comment: Some good related answers on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95581/the-limits-to-a-very-low-quality-answer.

Comment: @Sumurai8 "I like cows" is an appropriate answer if it's a question about Gentoo.

Answer (score 18):

I've always thought that the purpose of VLQ flags is to let the community handle the posts that should be deleted, without bothering the mods.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but posts VLQ-flagged are landing in LQ review queue, until some mod has handled them before, with the exceptions of VLQ flags on accepted answers, which always requires mod attention.

Yeah, it's unclear written and not well documented, but I flag as VLQ everything that has a good chance to be deleted in review queue.

Comment: for what it's worth VLQ flags push post into LQ review queue only since [July 2013](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190639/165773)

Comment: I used to do that, but since the mod queue has been mostly processed lately, mods are reviewing raw flags instead. Mods review VLQ flags a lot differently from the LQRQ, increasing the confusion.

Answer (score 9):

VLQ is for VERY low quality.  Low quality = down vote.  Very low quality = flag.  Very simple.

If it has severe formatting problems *such that it couldn't be reasonably edited*, then it should be flagged as such.  Basically, you need to decide which path a question/answer is on:

- Bad but fixable: this could be a useful question, with a little work by either the asker or someone else.
- Bad and not fixable: Anything useful that came out of this would be a result of essentially an entirely new post replacing it.

If it's the latter, VLQ away.  The point is largely to get the 20kers a list of things to use their delete votes on and the 2kers a list of things to use their recommend deletion votes on.

Comment: Is it the same for questions and answers?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?  The only difference for answers is there is a specific category of unsalvageable answers, "Not An Answer"s, while there is not a category "Not a question".

Comment: Should comment-answers ("the logic will be don't delete any thing unless you get a success from server,then it will work fine") be flagged VLQ? Should *wat* questions ("How to study the Spark. I felt confuse, Could u give me some advices about how to study a open source project and be a contributor fastest? Thank a lot.") be flagged?

Comment: Non answers are NAA. They might also be VLQ but the more specific flag is preferred. Way off topic questions should be closed, that's what close is for.

Comment: I do close them, but when should I closevote *and* flag VLQ?

Comment: Not for those. VLQ is for major problems that don't have a better way to handle them. Closed questions with a nonpositive score will be deleted automatically by the vacuum.

Comment: So I should VLQ when CVing isn't enough, like with time sensitive issues (low quality answers are being posted)?

Comment: "20Kers" is off by an order of magnitude since [March this year](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226092/165773 "see 'Task accumulates 6 RecommendDelete...'"). Six "Recommend Deletion" votes from **2K** users in LQ review queue now suffice to remove the answer (unless it has positive score or is accepted)

Comment: 20kers can cast delete votes, 2kers can cast recommend delete.  Not the same thing :)  But yes, i'll add that since it's a trivial difference.  (Sidebar, I don't actually like that change so probably why I've not internalized it; I think that might be part of why some users feel there's a big difference in how the LQ queue works vs mods - how the 2k-5k rep crowd votes.  I don't tend to see 2k rep as enough to have a high confidence in someone's ability to understand things; even at 2k I don't think I could've cast delete votes in the LQ queue and been all that accurate.)

Comment: that _trivial difference_ increased number of users who can delete from about 2,000 to 30,000 :)

Comment: See my edit to the comment ;)

Comment: well, given that positive score or accept blocks deletion, and (and this is a very very big AND) authors of deleted posts are totally free to undelete solely at their discretion, I would say system has quite a bit of safety net built in. Essentially queue deletions are limited only to happy path ("happy path" here being unambiguous decision of reviewers and voters that post isn't wort keeping, followed by total negligence of its author)...

Comment: ...the only glitch I am aware of is that "show removed posts" in reputation history is [turned off by default](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155999/165773 "feature request to fix this"). Quite a sad one if you ask me