# What can I use 100 flags for each day?

Tags: discussion, flags

After around 18 months on the site I've accumulated some 2400 helpful flags with a mere handful declined. Suddenly today several Very Low Quality flags were declined with the message

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that
>   requires their intervention

One could argue that all low quality posts can be dealt with without moderator intervention, so exactly what are these flags for?

I rarely use more than a handful of flags during any day, but frequently exhaust 50 close votes and the same number of up/down votes.

I can understand why moderators don't want flags when things can be dealt with otherwise, but the balance seems completely wrong.

Please - what *should* I do with 100 flags?

Comment: You don't *have* to use all your flags each day. We have enough to deal as it is!

Comment: Nothing. You have 100 flags for posts and 100 flags for comments. Don't try to use all those 200 flags. The only advantage is that you will never run out of flags if you see something on the site that requires _immediate attention_.

Comment: While @iStimple has pointed you to a query, please don't blindly flag posts without being sure they would **actually** meet the criteria of the flag.

Comment: @bluefeet It's entirely unclear what _does_ meet the criteria. Take [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25240448/1864610) as an example. The text adjacent to the VLQ flag button says something like 'This question has severe content or formatting problems and may need to be removed'. The question is a request for a hardware recommendation, which is off-topic just about everywhere on Stack Exchange. My VLQ flag on this was declined, yet clearly the question should be removed. The author of [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268269/1864610) clearly feels the same frustrations.

Comment: @ChrisF - then you need more moderators.

Comment: @MikeBrind - we have 17 on SO at the moment (admittedly not all of them are active), but it's been found that just adding more isn't scaling.

Comment: @MikeW You've got VtC privileges and you did vote to close that question but why did you feel the need to flag it as well?

Comment: @ChrisF sounds to me like the system isn't working.

Comment: I'm a pretty heavy downvoter, and I'd guess I rarely use more than 10-15 a day.  And maybe 5 close votes on a busy day.  Never hit a limit on either.  And I use a flag maybe once a week.  I kind of suspect that you're taking this whole thing far too seriously.  Go ride your bike!  Take a walk!  Take a cooking class!  Do something to get away from your computer!

Comment: @MikeW That question is not VLQ. It is "primarily opinion-based". It's also "about general computing hardware and software", or perhaps even just generally "has nothing to do with programming". I do agree that VLQ is too nebulous to really be useful, but that question you linked has far better reasons to flag it.
edit: I just noticed you yourself already closed it, so that makes it even sillier that you would want to VLQ flag it, rather than just closing it. I can't imagine I'd use that many flags at *all*, if I could deal with things that deserved closing directly.

Comment: @HotLicks You are not a heavy anything. See here: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/cv-stream

Answer (score 9):

> I rarely use more than a handful of flags during any day, but
>   frequently exhaust 50 close votes and the same number of up/down
>   votes.

Flags should be used for exceptional posts or problems that can't be dealt with through ordinary means. What you describe above sounds right to me, in that flagging should be much less common than voting to close or other kinds of voting. The fundamental design of the site is such that the community should be able to handle most moderation tasks themselves. You don't want a cabal of elected moderators to be the primary means of moderating posts on the site.

The role of the "very low quality" flag is [under debate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268269/the-very-low-quality-flag-is-broken) now that it has gone from being a moderator-only flag to one largely handled by the community in review. Until we figure out how these fit into things with both reviewers and moderators seeing them, I follow [the guidance we were provided](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160754/why-are-the-moderators-being-so-strict-with-quality-related-flags-recently) and decline any "very low quality" flags that don't point to something requiring our immediate attention. The fact that every validated "very low quality" flag turns a post into a review audit alone makes me cautious in accepting these.

For example, you flagged the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387883/does-the-nest-developer-program-allow-clients-to-be-open-source) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25233406/deleting-a-nest-client) as "very low quality", which I declined in both cases. While possibly off topic, there was no urgent, pressing need to delete those posts from the site. They were well-phrased and were developer-related questions. There are far worse things that people need to look at before handling questions like those, so even in the case where flagged posts feed into the review queues, those did not need to jump ahead in line over other bad questions in the close vote queue.

If moderators no longer handle "very low quality" flags, those flags will still need to be reserved for the exceptional cases where the community needs to act on something quickly, or people will just flag every single thing they vote to close and such flags will become meaningless.

Before I became a moderator, I flagged a lot of stuff, but very rarely used up my full allotment of 60 or so flags a day. That's as it should be, for flags should only be used on things you can't handle any other way.

Comment: So why can't we have more up/down/close? They should scale too.