# Incorrect declined flags warning

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags, declined-flags

> Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined - please review them before flagging this post!

I don't have any recent declined flags. This message appeared between when I didn't have recent declined flags and when I didn't have any recent declined flags.

To clarify, the message appeared when I didn't have any recent declined flags and still lingers while I have no recent declined flags.

[image: Bunch of helpful flags]

^ Here's a wall of flags.

Comment: Did the message also appear when you didn't have any recent declined flags?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes.

Comment: *[confused]* ... Redundant bug reports are redundant.

Comment: Define recent.  when was your last flag declined? and how many flags have you made since your last declined one?

Comment: Consider that the time it was declined counts, even if you cast it on your first day on SO and since learned better.

Comment: @SamIam Don't remember. UI doesn't say. But it was about 30 flags ago.

Comment: @bjb568 if you go to your profile, you can look and click on the number next to _helpful flags_, it will also tell you which ones are disputed and declined

Comment: @SamIam But not when I cast the flag or when it was approved/rejected/disputed/updated.

Comment: Maybe the message could also link to the last declined flag to avoid confusion.

Comment: Just add a possibility to the helpful-flags page to sort by day-processed (those still waiting before or after by date cast naturally).

Comment: Well, when I click on the "unhelpful flags" in your profile, I get all the flags you've raised, meaning the same list you just posted above.  I've just decided that this is useless, and hereby lodge a protest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the past week, 49 of your qualifying flags were processed, and 5 of them were declined. That's over 10%, [which is the threshold for warning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405) - so you've been warned.

Note that only 48 of the flags examined were *raised* by you during the past week (one was older) - however, all 5 of the declined flags were raised during the past week, so this doesn't really matter as far as the warning criteria goes.

Scroll down that list a bit further - the decline messages are in red and fairly easy to see.

Comment: Since when was a week "recent"? Especially on the internet!

Comment: (*grumbles something about Brad Larson and VLQ ambiguity…*)

Comment: Since [roughly February 26th](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405)

Comment: ambiguity or not, if you're double-flagging things you should expect *some* sort of push-back - that just wastes folks' time. Use the most appropriate flag possible, and then leave it at that.

Comment: Double-flagging? Huh? I was just flagging unsalvageable questions which is what I *thot* I should be doing…

Comment: [The Very Low Quality flag is broken](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268269/2371861)

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59231/discussion-on-answer-by-shog9-incorrect-declined-flags-warning).