# Can questions containing a code dump be considered as VLQ?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, low-quality-posts

I came over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26768927/trouble-with-simple-codefunctions) right now, and wondered if it should be flagged as VLQ because of

- The extremely poor title
- The lack of efforts of investigating possibly available sources
- The *"big"* code dump, without showing debugging efforts

Does this qualify this question to be flagged as VLQ? (I did so now)

---

To clarify:
The reason I'm asking here is, because I often see such kind of question, but retain to mark them VLQ, because at least the OP took the efforts to show some (mostly poorly formatted) code dump.

---

<sub>I've been close voting the question for the most appropriate reason also of course:</sub>

> <sub>Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.</sub>

Comment: a post that introduces the code with *"this is what I have so far"* is always a bad sign

Comment: _"big" code dump_: would you have liked for the user to paste only "Highest = Highest;" ? :) Would have helped to only paste the function findHighest ? He/she's a first time poster, assume an age of 10 year old / almost no programming experience / no debugging experience. Or do you want some assembler code too?

Comment: *assume an age of 10 year old / almost no programming experience / no debugging experience*  Minimum age here is 13; SO is for `professional programmers and [serious] enthusiasts` they are expected to know how to read How-To-Ask, actually read it and know how to debug.  Not sure what your point is @tehnicaorg

Comment: Gem of the Day: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26779357/please-any-help-is-highly-appreciated-plz

Comment: I'm hiting such questions very often lately, however I don't categorize them as VLQ, but as "asking about complete basics". I tried to asked here, how should I deal with such questions, but the general answer was to downvote, optionally flag for closure and pass to another one.

Comment: @Plutonix, my point is that a little kindness to newcomers goes a long way. It may be for professional and enthusiasts, but it don't think it's an exclusive club (for example "Questions asking for homework help must ..." makes me think it's for students too). I think he/she asked about a specific problem, explained what the desired behavior was and posted (in he/her's opinion ATM) a short code that could be easily tested (compiled/run) by others.

Comment: @tehnicaorg how is flagging something as VLQ, or downvoting, inherently "unkind"?  It tells the poster 'there is something wrong with this post'.  "Kindness" and degress thereof seems OT.

Comment: @Plutonix: it tells the poster that something is wrong, but not really what is wrong and what should be done to improve his question. Now I'm just trying to be in the poster's shoes at the beginning of a programming career. And this from the perspective of someone who asked very seldom questions (one question yesterday in 4+ years of visiting stackoverflow).

Comment: @Plutonix Flagging as VLQ actually doesn't tell the poster *anything* (he never sees it). It *does* open the strong possibility that the post will be summarily deleted. Now thats fine if it *deserves that*, but you shouldn't flag if the post is saveable. Totally agree with your other points though.

Comment: @tehnicaorg: SO suffers from scale. We don't have time to go around having a ten minute conversation on how to debug programs and ask questions with every single person who posts crap like this. We just don't. That's why the FAQ exists. If your question gets deleted because you didn't bother or think to read it then, frankly, that's your own fault. That's _life_. It requires a modicum of personal responsibility; yes, even in 2014, if I have anything to say about it. Better to learn the lesson now than to get blindsided by it when you go out into the real world.

Comment: On "big code dumps"... when [the code is more than ten times the length of the box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788974/) I've been figuring it's OK to VtC for the code alone: even if the question is OK it's unreasonable to expect anyone to read that.

Comment: Isn't VLQ basically code for 'unsalvagable'? I'd suggest any post that had code at least had a chance to be salvaged. (Although, downvoting because it's rubbish is a different matter entirely)

Comment: @technicaorg `it tells the poster that something is wrong, but not really what is wrong and what should be done to improve his question.` What is wrong about questions is written all over the site, all over the meta site, everywhere in the faqs, everywhere in the tutorials about how to ask, all over the questions strongly downvoted... Someone with reasonable will to ask a good question will find what's wrong with his post easily.

Comment: What is VLQ?___

Comment: @IllidanS4 Shortcut for **V**ery **L**ow **Q**ality. One of the standard flagging reasons you can select.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Casting your close vote (and or down vote) was appropriate here. But beyond that, just move on and the community will weigh in on what should happen as well. If you are feeling generous or see some redeeming qualities in the post, you can always attempt to edit it into a proper form.

There is no need to flag that as very low quality, and if you do it will most likely be declined as "not helpful". This is because a very low quality flag is essentially an indication that this needs immediate moderator intervention and that the question **cannot be saved**.

This question at least has some code, there was some effort, and something is clearly going wrong. In its current form, it is a poorly asked question and the *community* will deal with it appropriately. However, there is that small sliver of possibility the OP somehow manages to salvage this question by being attentive, and since they almost composed a good question it should not be flagged as un-salvageable and in need of immediate deletion.

In general, moderators prefer to allow the community come to consensus as opposed to directly handling the closure or deletion of posts. There are multiple reasons, but the two major ones are that it is more desirable to have community consensus for actions taken, and also that moderators simply do not have enough time to review every single question of this type.

Comment: "this needs immediate moderator intervention" Are there real cases of things that are so low quality that they need *immediate* moderator intervention that don't constitute abuse? I know the definition includes link-only answers which don't need either immediate attention nor moderator attention (theoretically, not that anybody really bothers deleting answers). It's [all confusing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268269/the-very-low-quality-flag-is-broken).

Comment: @bjb568 - If it is obvious that there is absolutely no possible way that anything could be done to make the question into something that was on topic at SO then that would need intervention, immediate is a relative term :) Basically this constitutes a question which is so riddled with babble that there is no sense in it and there never will be. That scenario is definitely an edge case and doesn't happen nearly as often as someone who posts something which is little more than an advertisement or abusive.

Comment: @TravisJ "HALLO I HAZ JQUERY PORBLEMZ <code>" can be edited and clarified. "asdfja;osirgjharith" is abuse. I don't see a use case at all for VLQ defined that way. The LQRQ will delete anything low-quality, so I think they're more correct than, well, what you're supposed to do and how mods handle flags.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen worse code-dumps. I would not say that it is **so** bad that it warrants **immediate deletion**. Remember, NAA and VLQ flags are sent with the intention of saying "This is crap; get rid of it NOW!"

The OP could fix the post into an answerable question (even though they don't in my experience). Definitely worth a VTC/Downvote though, if it gets closed the roomba will get it eventually.

I would not flag this as VLQ.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the others: this is "very low quality" but it does not warrant a "very low quality" *flag*. The key is that, while the question almost certainly *will not* be improved, that is subtly different from the hypothetical question which *cannot* be improved.

Comment: Maybe that's a cue to switch 'VLQ' to 'unsalvageable'

Comment: @Sobrique: That's the same thing. And "unsalvageable" is not the same as "won't be salvaged", which is my point.