# Yet another "why was my flag declined" question

Tags: discussion, support, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32279857/1768232) as VLQ.

> You can use SEBLOD. See a working example here: finalwholesale.com

Honestly, I almost flagged it as spam. What the heck is SEBLOD? How could this answer possibly be of any use to anyone? If the link were to be deleted the post would be even more useless.

Comment: SEBLOD is a content construction kit for Joomla: http://www.seblod.com/

Comment: The answer is trash because the question is horribly off-topic.  There is no evidence whatsoever that the OP is coding.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I declined it, because even if we don't know what SEBLOD is, it is an attempt at answering the question *as far as I can tell*.

If the answer is not helpful, downvote it and move on. VLQ is for stuff that is unreadable gibberish (think foreign language or pure nonsense).

I didn't have to time to do so when I handled the flag; searching for Joomla and SEBLOD on Google revealed it to be both an [OSS Joomla component](https://github.com/Octopoos/SEBLOD) with commercial backing (see [their FAQ](http://www.seblod.com/faq)). I've deleted the answer as it doesn't appear to be more than a comment.

A VLQ flag is *usually* declined, because it is really meant for *can't even make out what it is saying* answers. For real link-only answers use *Not an Answer*, and for these kinds of posts a custom flag will ensure more attention is paid to what the post is about (as we have far too many VLQs and NAA flags to process to give each a lot of attention). I tend to tolerate VLQs on link-only posts, but that's at my own discretion more than anything else.

Comment: I didn't flag it as NAA, I flagged it as VLQ. I agree that it is an answer, it's just a completely useless, link only answer.

Comment: @durron597: I know you did. So **downvote** it.

Comment: VLQ is also for link only answers.

Comment: But it is **not** link only. The link is an example of whatever SEBLOD is being used.

Comment: Link only is *Read this tutorial, it'll help you*. If you *do* know what SEBLOD is, there is an answer right there. Terrible, but not link-only.

Comment: I disagree with you, but the answer is at -5 now and I'm sure it will be deleted via meta effect soon, which I'm cool with.

Comment: @durron597: had I had the time to research (but I don't because I am processing 100s of flags per day), a google on Joomla and SEBLOD reveals it to be a [commercial hoster](http://www.seblod.com/).

Comment: Complete gibberish answers are also "not answers". If a link only answer (which is an answer! go to this link!) are not answers, then the VLQ flag is a strict subset of NAA and pointless. See: [The Very Low Quality flag is broken](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268269/1768232)

Comment: 6 letters of acronym does not make an answer less link-only. The answer has severe quality problems and should be deleted. The LQRQ would unanimously delete it, and I don't see why moderators should interfere and not do the same. Posts that aren't helpful (see. LQRQ autocomments), rather than just wrong or bad, should be deleted rather than downvoted. I think it's ridiculous to request that these posts be custom flagged with further explanation, that's not scalable and all link-only or otherwise crappy answer that'd be handled properly with VLQ/NAA->LQRQ shouldn't be handled by mods like that.

Comment: Let's not do this again, @bjb. If 6 is practically the same as 0 then 10 is pretty much 6; if 10 is effectively 0 then twice-ten is also 0. If twice-10 is 0 then 10 10s is also 0, as is 100 10s... Pretty soon you're back to "this novel-length answer contains a link **it must be link-only!**" And the mods are rolling their eyes. Be precise, flag answers that contain **no** information, or don't bother.

Comment: @bjb568 right, because you know for certain that SEBLOD is not a Joomla term here that every Joomla developer will know how to use, right? If this was Zope/Plone and the answer was *use ZODB Acquisition* with a link you'd summarily delete it too, I'm sure, but I'll happily light a fire at your feet for deleting an answer that actually answered the question. I'm not deleting posts that without their markup may look like an answer, this one qualified as such.

Comment: @durron597: I think CMs are working on better options for VLQ flags; I'm personally still not sure what they should ever be used for, I haven't seen any examples where other flags weren't more appropriate or the flag was just cast instead of a downvote or close vote.

Comment: @Shog One acronym can never be a valid answer. Yes or no can never be a valid answer. Anything with less than 200 bits of entropy can never be a valid answer. A pile of unimformative cow manure can never be a valid answer. The people at LQRQ know this and deal with the crap. Moderators don't know how to deal with LQ/NAAs and don't handle this properly. We need to delete more to raise (or maintain) quality, and this is one of the many posts that obviously doesn't meet even our ever-dropping standards.

Comment: @Martijn If *use ZODB Acquisition* is a valid and complete answer without further explanation, the question should be deleted as well.

Comment: @bjb568: it may well be downvote worthy, but *not up for moderator deletion*. SEBLOD turns out to be a Joomla add-on package that can do what the OP asked for. Sure, it is lacking in detail, but it was still an attempt an answering.

Comment: "An attempt at answering" is not immune from deletion. It's nowhere near a possibly-complete answer, and the little information it has, not including the link, doesn't meet the minimum character count. As-is, it serves as a broken window. Couldn't you at least convert it to a comment if you don't want the information lost?

Comment: Moderators are expected to act in... *moderation.* You might wanna consider earning 20K already, @bjb - then you can vote to delete answers based on your own criteria.

Comment: Sure, being conservative as a moderator is fine, but fiddling with the non-conservative LQ process that works and declining valid flags just makes everybody confused. ∃ official guidelines (somewhat), ∃ differing mod opinions, and ∃ shared expectations for pretty much all flaggers and reviewers – all of these differ. But the process without exceptions works and aside from exceptions shouldn't be interfered with. The answer in question *is* VLQ and seems to be rightfully deleted. The flag is valid.

Comment: And this is why people consider the site so toxic. There hasn't been a single site policy disallowing one-or-two-liners but the community sees fit to delete them indiscriminately. I mean, if you're then posting comments that end up being longer than your answer then it's a *sure* sign that it's your answer that needs to be expanded on, but some things are fairly self-explanatory and any elaboration is simply a bonus. It's a special kind of irony that *our* policies are *more* forgiving than... those of the community at large. Normally, it's the other way around and the mods get flak for that.

Comment: I'd totally be on board with making the character limit not count links though, @bjb568. I once suggested [removing links from an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer/225371#225371) so all that's left is a chunk of text seemingly leading nowhere. Perhaps the character limit could account for that.

Comment: @durron597: I think the difference between VLQ and NAA is that VLQ means "I can't tell if this is an answer or not" while NAA means "it's very clearly not an answer". But then I just take the former to mean "if I can't figure out whether this is an answer, it probably isn't" and that's how VLQ becomes a subset of NAA.

Comment: @BoltClock I agree with bjb that any answer with less than 200 bits of entropy is VLQ even if it attempts to answer the question. Of course that's not currently Stack Exchange policy so I don't flag it that way but if such little information IS an adequate answer, the question should be closed (simple typo). And, of course, link-only is VLQ because of link rot and spam / self promotion. But these things can be answers, and that's where the flags become different.

Comment: The answer doesn't answer the question. It is simple a spam post advertising finalwholesale.com. Any attempt to keep the answer is completely illogical. It does *not* give an example of an answer or anything to do with the OPs question. The question is, *are you going to have this debate EVERY time a spammer spews out terms you don't understand*? More to the point, are you actually going to *defend their spam*? It isn't a valid answer and never will be.

Comment: @Joehot200: the flagger didn't detect it was spam either. If you see spam, you flag it as spam. That gives the moderators more context too.

Comment: @Joehot200 Spam nuking something has extra consequences... -100 rep plus rate limiting the account. Thus, SE is very, very careful to only spam nuke stuff we are very sure is spam. I thought this was spam, but I wasn't sure *enough* to spam flag. I wanted the answer deleted, but not the other consequences.

Comment: The whole problem I see is that if you can actually read it, and it isn't a question, thanks or spam, then you probably shouldn't flag it unless you're in a low traffic tag and there isn't a large community of users to collectively act. If it can be dealt with through any other means than flagging, you should do that first. This post may have been a candidate for a spam flag, but most likely four or five downvotes would be just as effective.

Comment: I personally see it as common Stack Exchange Network spam.. spam like this is very common.

Comment: Even if it's not spam (after all it responds to OP's need) the author forgot to mention that he is probably (might be a coincidence) involved in development of this product ([see here, for example](https://www.facebook.com/seblodcck/posts/290526537802077)). But beside of that, I agree that it can be seen as a genuine attempt to point the OP in the right direction, so it may be valuable to future readers.

Comment: Often an answer with only one bit of entropy is still useful. If someone asks a question of the form, "is TCP or UDP more appropriate for such and such an application", "TCP" - a one bit, acronym only answer - might be exactly the answer the asker is looking for. Sure, a detailed explanation of why would make the answer even better, but plenty of askers are happy to get any answer at all.

Comment: @WarrenDew if it's not explained *why* TCP is more appropriate, how can it be useful? For all we known, the answer-giver is just guessing, or he thinks he knows the correct answer but doesn't, or he may be an expert on TCP&UDP and be 100% right.. if there is no explanation, we have no way to verify the answer's correctness and can't know if it's indeed useful

Comment: @TimCastelijns so downvote it. That's what voting is for.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm just commenting on Warren saying *Often an answer with only one bit of entropy is still useful* and his specific example to that

Comment: @TimCastelijns A lot of people trust that the people answering questions on StackOverflow are competent and likely to give the right answer.  Indeed, many of the people asking the questions don't understand the topic well enough to distinguish between a correct justification and an incorrect justification anyway.  Explanations are not that useful for these people.  You and I may not be like that, but many people are.

Comment: mfw reading this thread of comments to see "19 more comments" at the bottom. All this for a one-line-answer?