# Roomba very low score answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, automatic-deletion, wrong-answers

This is a request for a new type of [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba): a roomba on some answers instead of questions.

#### Proposal: a roomba for very low score answers

This is just a proposal, and conditions and naming can be refined, but for clarity I'll blockquote the proposal:

> If an answer matches all those conditions...
>
> - has a score of `-6` or less
> - has not been edited in the past `9` days
> - has not received any up vote in the past `9` days
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. These are "dead low", and are termed as `RemoveDeadLow`.

Potentially affected answers with the above conditions would be around 5,000 answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aa+score%3A-999..-6+lastactive%3A..9d

#### Context of the proposal

The idea is that it's somewhat easy to delete a question:

- either vote it down when you have [125 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down), and it may roomba as dead after 30 days
- either vote to close it when you have [3,000 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) and it may roomba as abandoned after 8 days
- either vote to delete it when you have [10,000 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

But it's hard to delete an answer:

- you need [20,000 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) to vote to delete an answer
- no alternatives: flags will get rejected with "*flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer*"

#### Alternative solutions

This question is about roomba deletion of answers. But note that there are alternatives where we could just have more users with the privilege to manually delete answers. Examples:

- We could have Bronze tag badge holders with just 10k rep allowed to vote to delete answers?
- We could have [Should "Very Low Quality" flags be offloaded entirely to tag experts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368875/should-very-low-quality-flags-be-offloaded-entirely-to-tag-experts)

Comment: Note that this depends on the tag to have sufficient traffic for an answer to get 6 downvotes. On the tags I frequent, I've never seen a non-spam answer with a score lower than -2. While I've got nothing against this proposal, its usefulness is limited to high-traffic tags.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth It may have limited usefulness (5000 less posts to manually vote to delete), but it's to be on the safe side of automatic deletion, and it may incentive downvoting poor answers.

Comment: Knowing that an answer is bad can sometimes be great information, for sure this can not be implemented on the meta sites and probably you will need some type of at least x numbers of answer already present.

Comment: There is a *lot* of signal in an answer that shows how *not* to solve a problem.  Extra merit when it is cargo-cult and juxtaposed against another answer that shows how to do it correctly in a non-intuitive way.

Comment: Uber-meta discussion: [Why is an answer that is so bad it is shown faded out kept around? Why not delete it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240427)

Comment: Is funny that the people against this idea will be the less affected. They all have 10k+, so the answers will not be lost for them if they are really that interested.

Answer (score 17):

There is an important difference between question and answers. The question helps me find my problem and the answers tell me what to and if I'm lucky also what **not** to do.

Removing questions that does not help me find any solution is sane, but are we sure that removing answer that tells me what I should not do is also sane?

I followed your link [Potentially affected answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aa+score%3A-999..-6+lastactive%3A..9d)

Time to check some php, to avoid sql injection I was thinking maybe I could `strip_tags(addslashes($str))`, hmm that seems [not to be a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4309292/5292302).

well let me use some `eval` to solve my issue in javascript instead [why not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13982602/5292302)?

---

These are some examples of how downvoted answers actually contains important information. I agree there are also lot of answers that does not contain any useful information, but to find automatically these answers you would need to refine your roomba rule, probably exclude answers that have a comment (it's probably a useful comment telling why it's not a good solution), maybe exclude if few answers on question.

In the end probably it's not worth the effort and your alternative solutions are better.

Comment: This is why we keep harping on the distinction between downvoting an answer, and flagging an answer for deletion. An answer isn't subject to deletion just because it has a negative score.

Comment: "if I'm lucky also what not to do" well, considering that people blindly copy and paste, I feel that it's more dangerous having wrong information than no information at all. Granted, the problem is that readers aren't critical of the information presented, and deleting this stuff just panders them, but also is the same people that make the code for our banks, health support systems, comunications infrastructure, etc.

Comment: @Braiam that's up to them, otherwise why have a voting system at all? _If_ people want to blindly copy and paste code, go ahead. For those that actually want to learn, bad answers are useful to have around.

Comment: @Bugs "that's up to them" so, if a programmer of your bank which uses `strip_tags(addslashes($str))` for their PHP and someone uses this vulnerability to siphon out your account. Your bank will claim that it was *you* the one that did the transaction and will do their damnest to not return your money. But it's up to them right? You need to understand that in todays world you should do everything possible to make stuff work right for everyone, even if you somehow end up with some losses. At the end, they will be less than if you did nothing.

Comment: @Braiam if a bank is employing a numpty that doesn't understand security concepts then it's the banks fault, no one elses. My money's covered regardless of how it's stolen so I also don't care.

Comment: A heavily downvoted answer is like a big flashing gray sign: "Warning! Don't do this!"

Answer (score 15):

I'd be *very much against this*.

That's because bad answers, with a wrong method or approach, have value too. They tell future visitors how *not* to do something. If you remove such answers automatically, people are doomed to repeat the same mistakes.

For example, if we were to delete the [*drop table and restore from backup* answer to a table lock problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4797328), how would people know that that's not a good idea? Put differently: *deleting that answer would **reduce** the usefulness of Stack Overflow, not improve it.*

This is also why moderators reject flags to delete downvoted, wrong answers with the default *flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer* message.

Also see [Why is an answer that is so bad it is shown faded out kept around? Why not delete it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240427/why-is-an-answer-that-is-so-bad-it-is-shown-faded-out-kept-around-why-not-delet)

Comment: Hm, this line of reasoning, although morally correct, contradicts how the content rating system currently works which is rather black and white: downvoted = not useful. However, the point still stands; there is little reason to delete downvoted answers. I mean what do you achieve. Rather than ghosted out, they're completely invisible.

Comment: "deleting that answer would reduce the usefulness of Stack Overflow, not improve it" this assessment should be done in the light of the Stack Overflow Driven Development. While you, kind sir, may be critical enough to know that such answer isn't recommended, there are swats of other users that aren't.

Comment: I feel bad for the answerer. You know, there should be a rep loss cap on answers so people can't be penalized too badly. Like max -50 rep loss from a downvoted answer, and further downvotes won't count.

Comment: @sag: why feel bad? They can almost always delete the answer. If the answer is marked accepted and it's not a self-answer, it'll require moderator intervention to delete. And rep loss *is* capped, when you reach 1 reputation you can't go lower.

Comment: @sag that's exactly what you shouldn't do, you put too much weight on reputation. Nothing bad is happening to someone who has content downvoted and loses a little reputation points as a result of it, they're not going to go hungry at the end of the month.