# A declined flag for a "Try this" answer is putting words in my mouth

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I recently flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52949266/1415724) for being low-quality and it was declined with the following message/reason:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

This to me had nothing to do with "technical inaccuracies" or a "wrong answer" and it wasn't what it was about, therefore I have to counter-decline that as being a valid answer for my flag.

Oh sure it solved the question since the OP accepted the answer, but the question is; "why"?

To me a "Try this" doesn't mean much. It's poor and doesn't explain what the fault was in the OP's code.

The OP states (that I fixed a few typos in an edit):

> I think that this is the way, but something is wrong and I don't know what.

To me, that says that they want to know what they did wrong; correct me if I'm wrong.

[The other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52949017/1415724) in the same question, at least shows some explanation.

Since there is no flag to explicitly state the reason for a VLQ flag, the only one available to do that would have been the one for moderation, and that would have also been declined.

"Try this" IMHO will always be of very low-quality. So, **why is it that these "Try this" answers keep getting passed VLQ flags?**

Should I have posted a comment under the answer in asking them "why they should try that"?

And if they would not have responded with a fair answer (and/or expanded on their answer) only then I should have flagged as VLQ? At least I'd of had a comment to support my concern and to help keep what Stack Overflow as I've been told to be, a place of "quality" questions and answers.

After all, there is always or usually is a "reason", right?

Potential future visitors (new coders) to the question/answer(s) would probably also like to know where the faults were.

Comment: Least I have one person who supports me/the question. Sorry, but the answers below do not satisfy what my question is about.

Comment: Sorry about that. What is the question about, then?

Comment: I've updated my answer, is it closer to your actual question now?

Comment: @StephenLeppik You're getting what I asked, yes; thanks.

Comment: '*Should I have posted a comment under the answer in asking them "why they should try that"?*' - I've tried this before and sadly it doesn't have the intended effect. The answerer just ends up thinking I'm the OP and dumps code or explanation in the comments.

Comment: The above actually happened to me yesterday and I realised it just shifts the whole focus on to me trying to explain to the person answering that I'm not the OP and I'm posing these questions to try and get them to improve their answer.

Comment: @Script47 Seems like downvoting is also a waste of time. I don't get how people still see "Try this" as being an acceptable answer. Well, I guess if the OP wasn't intererested in knowing why their code failed, then they're not serious about coding and just wanted "dah codez".

Comment: @Script47 Sometimes, it works.  If the answerer gets confused, and explains why the answer works, it can be edited into their question.  No need to try to explain that you're not the asker.  The reason you ask that is to nudge them into adding that into the answer, isn't it?

Comment: @fbueckert I'm all for editing questions (where effort is shown) but answers? No. I just feel that the cycle will continue endlessly if they don't do it themselves (meaning, somebody will always pick up after them and they won't really care) and truthfully, If *you* are going to provide an answer, it should be *your* responsibility to do it properly.

Comment: @Script47 Sure, we can teach them, but there's nothing that says we have to point it out step by step.  If you get a comment with the explanation, just edit it into their answer, and then leave a comment like, "Thanks!  I've edited your explanation into your answer.  Please try to add those types of explanations for other answers you contribute."  Show, and then encourage to continue the behaviour.

Comment: I find it rather odd though that a question which is poor/low quality can be flagged as VLQ but when the tables are turned on an equally bad / poor answer, it's declined/unacceptable. Personally, I think that this is a 2-faced system and it needs to be revised.

Comment: That's because we're more interested in keeping out the flood of crappy questions than we are in keeping out the occasional answer that has lots of room for improvement.

Comment: @Stephen I do not understand the change of title. FunkFortyNiner, is this revised title what you meant to ask?

Comment: @yivi You're going to have to take it up with the person who edited. I'm not touching my question. I seem to have no control over it.

Comment: I'm not asking to edit it. I'm asking if you believe the edit is accurate and reflects your intentions. I'm simply trying to see if I understood your question or not.

Comment: @yivi Oh sorry. Well, partly yes, but not entirely. My original title contained what I felt the declined flag message was about and if it's generic as you stated in your answer, then I find it's just a cheap and lazy cop out, if you ask me.

Comment: I will roll the the edit back, since that edit invalidates half of my answer. And frankly, the question _"why users use this flag"_ seems like a very different question to _"why was this flag declined with this message"_ to me

Comment: @yivi I made that change because people were closing this as a duplicate when there are other parts to the question that aren't answered there.

Comment: "Try this [some code that might actually work]" is a whole lot better than "I have the same problem, any update?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey Come on Robert; that is completely different and you know it.

Comment: Just trying to add a bit of perspective, that's all.  The code that was posted is apparently the correct solution, given the checkmark.

Comment: @Script47 Then add "Please [edit] your answer to add more information, instead of explaining in the comment section." ...

Comment: I agree that those answers are very low quality, but as answers said, they should not be VLQ flagged -- unless the rules change.

Comment: @user202729 I do but they generally don't or they ignore my comment and dump code / explanations in the comments at which point I give up and move on.

Answer (score 25):

> "Try this" IMHO will always be of very low-quality. So, why is it that these "Try this" answers keep getting passed VLQ flags?

Because people mistake the VLQ flag for an über-downvote. It *isn't*. They're crappy answers, but we shouldn't delete them for that.

> Should I have posted a comment under the answer in asking them "why they should try that"?

That would be an *excellent* idea.

> And if they would not have responded with a fair answer (and/or expanded on their answer) only then I should have flagged as VLQ?

Nope, because it's still not an über-downvote. "Very Low Quality" has strong emphasis on the "Very" part—it needs to be either unintelligible garbage, or obvious trolling such as "do X by pressing <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>" when X is anything other than "close the window that I'm in".

Comment: Here, have a +10 über-upvote. We can only hope that an answerer deletes such a downvoted-enough answer.

Comment: "Because people mistake the VLQ flag for an über-downvote." Lots of people treat them as just a regular downvote, not even an "uber" downvote.

Answer (score 9):

> "Try this" IMHO will always be of very low-quality

You seem to be confusing the meaning of "low quality" in regular usage, with the specific meaning the "low quality" flag has in the site.

A question that can be described as being of *low quality* does not immediately qualify to be flagged as VLQ.

VLQ, in the context of a SO flag means: *"unsalvageable garbage, unintelligible gibberish, or irrelevant nonsense"*.

Keep this specific meaning in mind instead of the regular use of the expression "low quality", and you'll have better luck with your VLQ flags.

> A declined flag for a “Try this” answer is putting words in my mouth

I think you know that that is a standard decline message for this flag, which applies whenever the flag is raised inappropriately.

In this case, you raised the flag because of the quality and usefulness of the answer (as far as I can understand from your question) and the mod is telling you that's not the proper use of VLQ flags.

Comment: I think there's a change coming to VLQ flags soon; right now, they just kick the can for action down the road to someone else.  Shog was proposing that maybe gold badge holders can instantly delete low quality answers.  As it stands, the VLQ flag is...kinda meh.

Comment: @fbueckert Shog [was actually suggesting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368890) even silver and bronze badge holder to gain this new privilege. And I loved that proposal. But I'm answering about how things are now. That change can easily be approved in 6 to 8 weeks. Add another 6 to 8 weeks for implementation....

Comment: That's true.  I'm also pointing out the suspect efficacy of the current usage; ie. it...might make something happen?  It's going to be super inconsistent.

Comment: @fbueckert I seriously hope they don't do that, we have enough answers wrongly deleted as-is.

Comment: @Stephen if you read the proposal, it actually says to get rid of the VLQ flag for answers (we already have NAA which is much more useful), and repurpose the VLQ flag for _questions_.