# Programming vs using frameworks

Tags: discussion

I was for the billionth time scrolling through SO on a low intense period at work thinking "*where are all the programming questions?*"

Most question in my feed are of the category "**How do I do [X] with [framework/library/tool/etc] [Y]?**" or "**I get [error] in [framework/library], how do I solve it?**" While useful for people looking to do exactly that they are usually not of general programming interest (in my humble opinion).

What do I want to ask then? The [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)-guidelines defines good/bad question titles as follows:

> Examples:
>
> - Bad: C# Math Confusion
> - Good: Why does using float instead of int give me different results when all of my inputs are integers?
> - Bad: [php] session doubt
> - Good: How can I redirect users to different pages based on session data in PHP?
> - Bad: android if else problems
> - Good: Why does str == "value" evaluate to false when str is set to "value"?

All of the good examples are general programming questions, rather than for example framework configuration questions. How should a user be able to navigate between them in a meaningful way?

My opinion, for what it is worth, would be a good separation between general programming questions and very framework specific questions. My perspective is not that framework specific questions and issue do not add value to the community, but rather that it takes time to filter out, say general C# or assembly questions (which I happen to be interested in, of course there are framework experts as well!).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a good separation? How were you thinking that should be achieved?

Comment: It's really just a symptom of the natural evolution in programming, where a lot of things have already been written and distributed as libraries/frameworks.

Comment: Also, many questions I see that are presented as framework/library/tool questions really are just general language questions, because the OP doesn't understand what the actual problem is.

Comment: @Don'tPanic like [jQuery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/218388)?

Comment: @Script47 Not naming any names ;-)

Comment: @Script47 Absurd.  It's actually a requirement for me to add two integers together using jQuery instead of native javascript.  I'm not allowed to not use it.

Comment: The odds that any "general programming" questions are left unasked after a decade and 16.7 million questions are zero.  If you can't find any then that's actually a good sign, maybe users are actually using Google first :)

Answer (score 10):

You can have very specific questions that won't be useful to anyone but the OP that don't use any frameworks, and you can have very widely applicable questions that are useful to millions of people that use a framework or library.  How localized a question is has nothing to do with whether or not it uses a framework.

Yes, *some* frameworks are not very popular, and so questions relating to them will have a smaller audience, just like some programming languages are not popular and have a small audience.  There's nothing inherent to the use of lack of a framework or library that makes a question very localized or not localized.

Also keep in mind that SO is here to answer **practical** programming problems.  This isn't Computer Science.  And in the real world, a *very* large portion of practical problems involve the use of libraries or frameworks in some way.  Knowing how to work with them (both in general, and also the specific frameworks that you're working with for a given problem) is an *essential* still of practical programming.

Comment: I understand know how my question has been misunderstood, does it make more sense now?

Comment: @flindeberg If you want to ignore certain topics, then ignore the tags associated with those topics.

Answer (score 2):

Those are examples of bad/good *titles*, which is a related but distinct issue from question quality.  As for non-framework-specific questions, they are mostly done. See [the future of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368875/should-very-low-quality-flags-be-offloaded-entirely-to-tag-experts/374490#374490).